# I'm having troubles selecting data from a MySQL databse

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to make a column be included only if the ID of the column is in the web address. But it's not returning the data. Any suggestions?

This is what my code looks like

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM orders WHERE `orders`.`id`= '$form_id'";
$order_data=mysql_query($sql);
$form_id=$_GET['id'];
```

If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: You're trying to use the `$form_id` value before it even exists.  Things have to exist *first* before you can use them.  Also, side note, this is wide open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this

```
$form_id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM orders WHERE `orders`.`id`= '$form_id'";
$order_data=mysql_query($sql);
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem

Comment: Well, it'll solve *a* problem.  But it enables the SQL injection problem.

Comment: Maybe you should mention [exploits of a mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).